# How to specify a default state in AngularJS ui-router module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is what I'm trying to achieve: When the user enters a URL that is not matched by any of the URL patterns of the states configured in the `$stateProvider`, the state should be set to a default state that is named for instance `'notFound'`. Entering this state must leave the URL untouched, so the user has the chance to correct it. This is why I'm not using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`.

Currently I'm working with the following workaround: In my main controller I check if

```
$state.current.name == ''
```

If this is the case, I set the `'notFound'` state.

```
$state.go('notFound', {}, { location: false });
```

However, it seems a bit like a hack because I assume there is a way to configure all of this in module.config() but I don't know how. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself: It is possible to use regular expressions for parameters in the URL. So you can define a "catch-all" state as the last state registered in the `$stateProvider` like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('notFound', {
    url: '{path:.*}',
    templateUrl: '/notFound.html'
});
```

If no other URL pattern matches, this state will be selected and the complete path can be accessed via `$stateParams.path`.

Comment: This helped me a lot thanks, you can accept your own answer btw :)